# garage door opens all the way, then slides down a little

Tags: doors, garage

this just started happening.  The garage door opens just fine.  when it gets to the stopping point, it sometimes slides down several inches.  Then the motor comes back on and pulls it up again.  this can happen 2-3 times on an opening before it stays up.

Comment: It would really help if you'd tell us something about the actual opener. Revise with your model information. We're throwing darts here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust (or have adjusted by someone else) your garage door so that it operates correctly by hand (detached from the opener.)

Openers are **not** meant to compensate for broken or maladjusted garage door springs.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Out-of-spec springs may trip a force detector, but it doesn't explain why a door would drop down when the opener stops. Also, what would trigger the opener to stop and restart?

Comment: If the door is properly adjusted for manual operation, you raise it, and it **stays put there.** If it is inclined to slip down, the springs are out of adjustment.

Comment: There's nothing that can slip in a healthy system, even if there's pressure on the springs. Also, if there is movement, it'll happen at the _start_ of the cycle, not the end.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal, the springs are not wound tight enough to keep the door in its high position. For example, if there were no springs, the door would slam back down shut when released. OP's condition is a subset of no springs. Once the opener stops, the motor releases its pull on the door. The door then starts sliding down again. Depending on the design or lack thereof of the door opener the limit switches could be released and turn the motor on again.

Comment: Just a caution, garage door springs hold massive force.  If not careful/not knowing what you are doing, can hurt bad or even kill if it does not go right/something breaks.

Comment: Which is one reason many people do choose to hire someone else for that part.

Comment: +1 to using a pro for springs. I consider myself handy (>20 years in the carpentry trade with plenty of touch in related specialties), but there's no way in heck I'd mess with those.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

1. Is there slack in the chain or drive mechanism that is allowing the door to go down a bit when the motor stops?
2. Is the brake/clutch mechanism that keeps the drive mechanism fixed when the motor stops worn or damaged?
3. Is the connection from the drive system to the door loose?

Answer (score 0):

The only real explanation for the opener starting after stopping is a failure or slippage in the stop switch or *internal* movement. Slack in the chain, maladjusted springs, and other external sources of movement don't explain that.

I would pull the cover and watch what happens with the motor cog while this is happening. Does it rotate backward? Does something spin freely?